# Google Compute Engine websocket secure (wss//) setting

Tags: websocket, google-cloud-platform, ratchet

I need help to enable wss in with google compute engine instance ip. My google cloud compute engine instance ip is: 35.192.96.70

I started ratchet server like this:

```
$allowed_origins = ['localhost','35.192.96.70', '127.0.0.1'];
$app = new Ratchet\App('35.192.96.70', 8080, '0.0.0.0');//App(hostname, port, 'whoCanConnectIP', '')
$app->route('/comm', new Comm, $allowed_origins);
$app->run();
```

and in js file I'm connecting to websocket server like this:

```
const wsChat = new WebSocket("wss://35.192.96.70:8080/comm");
```

but its not connecting. But if I use 'ws' instead of 'wss' like this:

```
const wsChat = new WebSocket("ws://35.192.96.70:8080/comm");
```

then its working.

I need help how to make wss work. What changes/settings I need to do in google cloud dashboard or in apache setting or else ?

Thanks for help,

Answer (score 0):

If on SSL, Ratchet won't work unless you make some changes on your server.

Enable mod_proxy.so

Enable mod_proxy_wstunnel.so

Open httpd.conf and add this: ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://YOUR_SERVER_IP_OR_DOMAIN:PORT/

e.g. ProxyPass /wss2/ ws://www.abc.xyz:8080/

From your front-end, you can connect like this:

const wsChat = new WebSocket("wss://YOUR_SERVER_IP_OR_DOMAIN/wss2/comm");

However, if you are wondering how to edit httpd.conf on WHM, here is how:

After enabling those services (mod_proxy.so and mod_proxy_wstunnel.so), log in to WHM,
go to "service configuration" => "Apache configuration" => "include editor" => "pre main include",

select a version of your choice or choose "All versions". The file name should be "pre_main_global.conf'

All your new configuration can be written in that textarea without tampering with httpd.conf directly. The configurations will be loaded on Apache start-up.
Once you put the Proxypass directive there, restart your server and there you go.